# Strange async behaviour

Tags: dart, dart-async

I am trying to understand how Dart performs async calls.

Given the following code:

```
main() {
  test("test", () async{
    await myCall( );
    print( "done");
  });
}

Future myCall( ) async{

  ["0","1","2"].forEach( (item) async{
    print( "about to callback");
    await futurePrint( item);
    print( "done  callback");
  });
  print( "done mycall");
  return new Future.value();
}

Future futurePrint( String str){
  print( "string = ${str}");
  return new Future.value();
}
```

I would expect the output to be

```
about to future print 
string = 0 
done future print 
about to future print 
string = 1
done future print 
about to future print 
string = 2 
done future print 
done mycall
done
```

But the code actual output is

```
print( "done mycall");
about to future print
string = 0
about to future print
string = 1
about to future print
string = 2
done
done future print
done future print
done future print
```

Why does the 'done myCall' occur as the first line printed, not the last?
Why do the 'done future print's occur after the 'done' print?

How do I get `myCall` to only return when the array iteration is complete?

Comment: You can also use `await Future.wait(["0", "1", "2"].map((..) async => ...))` to do an async operation for each element, then wait for all the results.

Answer (score 1):

`["0","1","2"].forEach(<callback>)` doesn't wait for futures returned by `<callback>`.

If you do

```
Future myCall( ) async {

  for(item in ["0","1","2"]){
    print( "about to callback");
    await futurePrint( item);
    print( "done  callback");
  });
  print( "done mycall");
  return new Future.value();
}
```

it should do what you expect.

Comment: Why do I need to use that  specific iterator? Why cant I use the closure iterator?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, `forEach()` (where you pass your closure to) does not wait for your closure to complete, in fact it doesn't do anything with a returened value. It is fire and forget. Therefore no order of execution is preserved if async execution starts within the closure.